# What's the correct syntax to reset count when met value 1 in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How do I reset `rank()` when meet value 1 in SQL Server 2008 (no `Lag` function)?

As you can see from the code, column 'Column_Reference' doesn't produce the results I wanted. Any idea how to fix this??

```
case when 
         (case when Datediff(day, s2.DutyStartDateLocal, s1.DutyStartDateLocal) = 1 then 1
         else 0
         end) = 0 then 1--+ (-1*row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY s1.CREWID  order by s1.CREWID,s1.DutyStartDateLocal))
     ELSE 
      row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY s1.CREWID order by s1.CREWID,s1.DutyStartDateLocal)
         END as Column_Reference
```

```
Current result of column_reference    Ideal result
--------------------------------------------------
              1                           1
              2                           2
              3                           3
              4                           4
              1                           1
              6                           2
              7                           3
              8                           4
              9                           5
              1                           1
             11                           2
             12                           3
             13                           4
             14                           5
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, edgar. Your question doesn't include enough detail to give you a meaningful answer. Have a look at [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/), then edit your question with the additional information.

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to a more recent version of SQL Server!  It will at least be supported!

You want to assign groups to ranges and then use `row_number()`.  Unfortunately, cumulative sums are not allowed, but you can use `apply`.

I can't follow what columns and tables you care about.  It is very important that you have an ordering column -- which I will call `DutyStartDateLocal` but could be multiple columns.

The structure is:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by t.crewid, g.grp order by DutyStartDateLocal) as seqnum
from t cross apply
     (select count(*) as grp
      from t t2
      where t2.crewid = t.crewid and 
            t2.DutyStartDateLocal <= t.DutyStartDateLocal  and
            t2.colref = 0
     ) g ;
```